# Trying to resolve a promise to test inner code

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise

This is a snippet from my code:

```
let that = this;
console.log('is logged');
this.$translate.onReady().then(() => {
  console.log('is ready - never logged');
  that.$translate.refresh().then(() => console.log('DONE - never logged'));
});
```

and in my test, I'm trying to invoke `this.$translate.onReady()` so that `console.log('is ready - never logged');` is logged. And in turn `refresh()` is called.

How can I achieve this?

```
spyOn($translate, 'onReady').and.returnValue(
{
  then:function() {
    console.log('is logged');
  }
});
```

Comment: if onReady is never resolved it's totally normal behaviour, you probably need to refactor your test, could you elaborate a little on its context / what you are trying to test : the callback itself ( what it does ), when it is resolved ? From your post, one could think that you are trying to test the Promise implementation itself. Could you post what test / assertion lib you are using. If your spy replaces the returns value with a `then` which does not take any callback as args it's normal you don't see anything.

Comment: Well just `return Promise.resolve(…)`?